# Variable initialized to bar_index on a candle before the real time bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

let's say we are on the first candle on the chart, its bar index is 0 and i set a variable:
`var index = bar_index`

later on we are on the 100th candle on the chart which is a real time bar, its bar_index is 0 right? So my question is since i've set `var index = bar_index`, will index be equal to 99 or it will still be 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var` keyword is used to initialize a variable only once. Unless you use the `:=` assignment operator on this variable, it will keep its value which in your example is zero.